# sql table random numbers into multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

new here - but would appreciate any help
I have a table with one column - this column has numbers from 1 to 1000
I would like to break this column up into ten columns - so I would have 10 columns and 100 rows in my new table
I would also like the numbers to be in random order

Any help would really be appreciated -- thanks in advance

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: We love that you're here with us and we want to see your code so we can help you fox it. Post your attempt and show us what problem you're having.

Comment: Sorry I am using SQL 2008 R2

Comment: Right now I don't even have an attempt - I just have one table with 1000 rows all in one column - and I am trying to break them up into ten columns - random order

Comment: Try using PIVOT function

Comment: Right now table name is Tbl_num - one column which is named Num - and consists of 1000 rows which contain (1-1000)

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select max(case when seqnum % 10 = 0 then number end) as number_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 1 then number end) as number_2,
       . . .
       max(case when seqnum % 10 = 9 then number end) as number_10
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by newid()) - 1 as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor(seqnum / 10)
```